# Doctrine custom type - save sql expression

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create custom doctrine type that simply increments an integer by one. I want to do it on a database level, with simple x=x+1 where x is the column name.

But I cannot find how to reference the column name and how to force (if necessary) to save it unquoted.

Is there any way to do this with custom type?